# How to run specific files in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I can run one file only by `phpunit --filter=Test1`

But I want to run two files . How can I achieve . I tried like..

`phpunit  --filter=Test1,Test2` but no executed test only

`phpunit  --filter=Test1, --filter=Test2` but Test2 execute only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use regular expressions. For example

```
phpunit --filter 'Test1|Test2'
```

You can use offical documentation https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/textui.html#command-line-options

Comment: Alternatively, in this case, you could also use `phpunit --filter Test` which would match both `Test1` and `Test2`. But also `TestSomethingElse` which might not be desired.